# Upload files from vsftpd ftp client in /tmp and once they are uploaded, move them to original folder

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, upload, centos6.5

I'm having issues with my application. The scenario is that, there is a php cron which is running every 1 minute and it processes the uploads folder, wherein, files are uploaded via ftp server(vsftpd). If the server is uploading a file which is 1GB, the php cron will process the files, even if it is not uploaded completely. I can't change the cron timing, but I want to know if, whether vsftpd has any function, by which can upload the file in `/tmp` and then move to original folder once the upload is complete?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not have this function built in.
There are solutions to this though.

The probably best is, to tell the uploading program to upload it with a different name, e.g. `file-whatever.txt.incomplete` and once the upload is completed rename it it the normal name.
The advantage is:
The rename is fast (since the file is on the same filesystem).
If a upload doesn't finish correctly, it doesn't get renamed.
Disadvantage of course, you need changes in both the uploading process and the PHP cronjob (to ignore `*.incomplete` files).

The other solution is to upload it to a different folder like you suggested and watch it with something like [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en).
With that you can watch a folder and move completed files to a different folder.
Disadvantage: if a upload fails halfway through it will still get moved and possibly processed.